# share a file from raw folder to another apps

Tags: android, share

i want to share a sound from raw folder to another app with sharingIntent

i use this code to share text and string

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Uri` to share your file by replacing.

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
```

Into this that, parses an `URI` instead.

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(
     Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
     Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name
));
```